# Compile embedded C code project using ARMCompiler6 in WSL

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux, armclang

I'm attempting to migrate the workflow for an ARM embedded C code project from Cygwin to WSL and PowerShell. I'm using ARM Development Studio 2019.0-1 and its ARMCompiler6.12.1.
I setup WSL, moved to my project dir, switched to bash, ran make, and got the following error:

"bash: line 1: armclang: command not found"

I expected this to be a path issue so I compared the $PATH env variable in Cygwin to WSL's

/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Arm/Development Studio 2019.0-1/sw/ARMCompiler6.12.1/bin:

/mnt/c/Program Files/Arm/Development Studio 2019.0-1/sw/ARMCompiler6.12.1/bin

I also added the following line to $PATH since make.exe is there, but same thing:

C:\Program Files\Arm\Development Studio 2019.0-1\bin

Any help getting my embedded C code project to compile using ARMCompiler6 in WSL is appreciated.

Comment: You can't run windows executables in WSL, which is Linux. You'll need to install Linux toolchain.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have run notepad++ through wsl bash which is a windows executable.  Am I misunderstanding you? Is that a different situation somehow?

Comment: Well, looks like I was wrong. There is a facility allowing to run windows executable from WSL... Still would suggest installing Linux toolchain if you are planning on WSL as build environment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.